# T-SQL: Select some data with a cursor

Tags: sql, select, cursor

I got a "situation": There is one database on ~80 PC's with known IP which are stored in a agent's table on central server. I would like to select (as a test) some data from each database. I began:

```
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
   SELECT agent_id, agent_ip_address FROM DB_FF.dbo.agents
      WHERE agent_ip_address IS NOT NULL
----------------------------------------------------- 
DECLARE @agent_id int, @agent_ip_address varchar(MAX)
-----------------------------------------------------

OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @agent_id, @agent_ip_address
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
      BEGIN
         SELECT TOP 3 * FROM @agent_ip_address.[DB_SLAVE].[dbo].[cheques];
      END
```

The problem is when I specified "." between [DB_SLAVE] and [dbo]. Any ideas how can I do it (do it - intelligent)? Thanks.

Comment: Is @agent_ip_address an *actual dotted IP address* or a linked server name? if its not a linked server (it probably should be) you would need OPENDATASOURCE. Is this on a lan? what authentication is being used?

Comment: Server authentication and that's another problem. IPs are dotted.

Comment: So you need to access 50 servers over the public internet?

Answer (score 0):

If it's an option - maybe use a console app or similar to do this - so in stead of the SQL cursor you'd have a dataReader (in whatever language you use) and then you can do the dynamic SQL you're trying to run.